# What does the line about the Tower of Babel mean in Ishay Ribo's "Keter Melucha"?

Tags: song-lyrics, hebrew-language, ishay-ribo

In Ishay Ribo's song "[Keter Melucha](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVKoNZloRvQ&ab_channel=%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95) / כתר מלוכה" (Royal Crown), a song written about, essentially, COVID and lockdown, there's a stanza that goes like this:

> בין ויקהל לפקודי
> אין איש בעיר ובשדה
> כבר אין מול מי להתנהל
> מגדל בבל שוב מתבלבל
>
> Between Vayakhel and Pekudei<sup>1</sup>
> There's no person in the city or the field
> There are no people to interact with
> The Tower of Babel again confuses
> <sub>(my own translation)</sub>

...it sounds better in Hebrew (and rhymes!).

What does the Tower of Babel line have to do with anything? Traditionally, the Tower was the cause of the mixing of languages and the dispersion of people around the world; what relevance does it have here, especially after the line about there being nobody in the city or fields?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Names of weekly Torah readings. This year, those two were read [March 15-21](https://www.hebcal.com/sedrot/vayakhel-pekudei-20200321).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The central theme of the song is being alone. This is illustrated with the lines "no one in the city or field", "no one to interact with", even in that first stanza. A little further on, in the chorus there are the lines "ולא להיות לבד" ("and not to be alone") and "ואיך נדע להתאחד בפרוד הזה" ("and know how to deal with this separation"), with many other examples extant in the song.

The Tower of Babel here represents the scattering and separation it caused. Before the Tower, all the people of the Earth spoke the same language and were able to connect with each other. After the events of the Tower, everyone was separated - languages were split up, nations could no longer interact in the same way.

The song here is comparing lockdown (Israel went into enforced lockdown in April and March 2020 to prevent the spread of COVID-19) with the Tower of Babel, because both situations meant that people are separated and can no longer interact the same way they did beforehand.
Both situations caused (in the eyes of the song) a large amount of people who once could interact to no longer be able to interact.

The word "מתבלבל" doesn't just mean "confuses" as in "this test confused me". It can also mean "mixed up" or "causes disruption". The wording of "שוב מתבלבל" implies that it is once again causing the same disruption as last time (i.e. dispersing people).
You can read the line as "again, the disruption of the Tower of Babel", which means that it's just like the disruption caused by the Tower (as opposed to "the Tower is once again causing disruption").